# angular2 interpolation and element (attribute vs property)

Tags: dom, angular, typescript

After reading angular 2 guide about template expression/ property biding / interpolation, i'm a little confused, here is what confuse me :

> Attributes initialize DOM properties and then they are done. Property
>   values can change; attribute values can't.
>
> For example, when the browser renders ,
>   it creates a corresponding DOM node with a value property initialized
>   to "Bob".
>
> When the user enters "Sally" into the input box, the DOM element value
>   property becomes "Sally". But the HTML value attribute remains
>   unchanged as we discover if we ask the input element about that
>   attribute: input.getAttribute('value') // returns "Bob"
>
> The HTML attribute value specifies the initial value; the DOM value
>   property is the current value.
>
> The disabled attribute is another peculiar example. A button's
>   disabled property is false by default so the button is enabled. When
>   we add the disabled attribute, its presence alone initializes the
>   button's disabled property to true so the button is disabled.
>
> Adding and removing the disabled attribute disables and enables the
>   button. The value of the attribute is irrelevant, which is why we
>   cannot enable a button by writing Still
>   Disabled.
>
> Setting the button's disabled property (say, with an Angular binding)
>   disables or enables the button. The value of the property matters.
>
> The HTML attribute and the DOM property are not the same thing, even
>   when they have the same name. This is so important, we’ll say it
>   again.
>
> Template binding works with properties and events, not attributes.

but when i write a simple attribute, using interpolation inside attribute string, its work, when i change the `myValue` component variable, the change is reflected on the dom

**Template**

```
<a href="{{myValue}}">tata</a>
<button (click)="change()">test</button>
```

**Component**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'my-test',
    templateUrl: 'test.component.html'
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {

    myValue : number = 0;

    ngOnInit() { }

    public change() {
        this.myValue = (Math.random() * 10)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In layman's terms, property binding and interpolation are two separate ways to "pass" a component instance variable's value to the template.

You can either do one of the following interchangeably, and the Angular documentation even says that interpolation is slightly favored for readability:

```
<a href="{{myValue}}">tata</a>
<a [href]="myValue">tata</a>
```

You couldn't do the following. Because this will change the attribute property `href`, but since attribute properties are one-time changes made during initialization, it won't be reflected to the user:

```
<a [attr.href]="myValue">tata</a>
```

Comment: thank you, another little thing; the chrome debug tool show the attribute or dom property?

Comment: If you're debugging JavaScript/TypeScript and expand an object created from a method like `getElementById()`, chrome will show you DOM properties. Interestingly, one of those properties is `attributes`, which contains the values for... you guessed it, that element's attributes. When you look at the acutal DOM in the "elements" tab, it will only reflect changes to attributes.

Answer (score 2):

This is property binding, not attribute binding:

```
<a href="{{myValue}}">tata</a>
```

When the `href` property of the `<a>` element is updated, the `<a>` element itself reflects the current value to the DOM attribute.

As @JohnV already mentioned, attribute binding would be

```
<a attr.href="{{myValue}}">tata</a>
```

or

```
<a [attr.href]="myValue">tata</a>
```